# Em Data science e Programação, o que significa a expressão "Pipeline"?

Tags: ciência-de-dados, pipeline

**O que significa a expressão "Pipeline"?**

Comment: Um cadeia ordenada de processos cujo a saída de um processo é a entrada do próximo.

Comment: Está correto, vim só complementar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(computing)

Answer (score 0):

**Um pipeline em ciência de dados é o conjunto de processos que convertem dados brutos em respostas acionáveis ​​a questões relacionadas a negócios.**

- Automatizam o fluxo de dados da origem ao destino, fornecendo, em última análise, insights para a tomada de decisões dos negócios.
- Automatizam os processos de validação de dados; extrair, transformar, carregar (ETL); modelagem e machine learning; revisão; e output para um data warehouse ou plataforma de visualização de dados.
- Eliminam muitos processos manuais sujeitos a erros envolvidos no transporte de dados entre locais que podem causar latência de dados e gargalos.